# .vimrc for IntelliJ Idea's vim plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, vim

I am using the vim plugin for IntelliJ Idea.
Where should I place the .vimrc for that plugin.
Using Windows XP

Comment: Sorry friend - the IntelliJ vim plugin is just an emulator - it doesn't use your vimrc

Comment: I was able to get RubyMine to pick up my `~/.ideavimrc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo %homepath%
```

gives me my "home directory" on Windows XP,
where I need to put my .vimrc.

Comment: Does this really work? I don't think my intellij vim plugin doesn't use a .vimrc.

Comment: This doesn't work. IntelliJ Idea Vim does not support `.vimrc` file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585687/is-there-a-way-to-get-ideavim-to-honor-the-mappings-from-my-vimrc-file. Who voted this up?

Comment: This answer is not helpful, since as I (and others have noted), you shouldn't be using `.vimrc` with the vim plugin. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73627916/758334) for more detail.

Answer (score 55):

The latest version of the plugin will read settings from a file named `.ideavimrc` in the home directory.

On *nix, the home directory can be accessed at `~`.

On Windows, you can use the `%HOMEPATH%` environment variable. (Normally, "C:\Users\<User Name>" or "C:\Documents and Settings\<User Name>", depending on your Windows version.)

Comment: or _ideavimrc on windows, in keeping with vim's conventions.

Answer (score 11):

If you rename your `.vimrc` to `_ideavimrc` in your ~ directory (/Users/ in windows)

Underscore is used instead of the `.` in windows for vim apparently

IntelliJ will honour it

Was tearing my hair out for a while getting this to work.

Answer (score 7):

On my mac i simply ran `ln -s "$HOME/.vimrc" "$HOME/.ideavimrc"` to create a symlink so IntelliJ would use the same `.vimrc` as my standard vim.

My `.vimrc` is very simple. However, if there is config that is incompatible between IntelliJ and vim then you might have issues with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the vim plugin for JetBrains doesn't effectively support the full functionality of a `.vimrc`. The file that the plugin uses is called `.ideavimrc`. This is what you should use and it should be placed in your home directory (see this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24415248/758334) for details, particularly for Windows).

I have a very comprehensive `.vimrc` that I use. Unfortunately, I had to pare that down quite a bit to work as `.ideavimrc`. You can look at the gists to see the differences. For what it's worth, it's still provides nice functionality, including buffer switching across tabs and splits.

- [.ideavimrc](https://gist.github.com/subfuzion/1ce83c3496e17646dbfd46aa327a5970)
- [.vimrc](https://gist.github.com/subfuzion/a704d6c2d495f58204d232c29ab1a251)

So why not just use the same file (i.e., `.vimrc`) for both? Well, for one thing, you need some settings in `.ideavimrc` that give precedence to the vim plugin for certain keyboard shortcuts that conflict with the IDE. See the top of my [.ideavimrc](https://gist.github.com/subfuzion/1ce83c3496e17646dbfd46aa327a5970) for my settings (for example, `sethandler <C-B> a:vim`). The other thing is that it seemed that when my more complicated `.vimrc` couldn't be processed, other settings (such as just `set noerrorbells`) also wouldn't take effect.