# RubyMine + .gvimrc + .vimrc?

Tags: vim, rubymine

I just installed the Vim plugin for RubyMine, but I cant figure out where to put my configure files for vim.

I want the same color code highlight as specified in the configure files.

Any ideas?

I'm using OS X.

Comment: You're talking about the IdeaVIM plugin, right?  If so, this seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138992/vimrc-for-intellij-ideas-vim-plugin, but the answer there was the home directory

Comment: The home directory does not work. Both gvimrc and vimrc is being ignored by RubyMine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the same color code highlight as specified in the configure files.

I don't think you can.  Did you look at [RubyMine's color schemes](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1154)?

> I cant figure out where to put my configure files for vim.

The Vim plugin seems to add Vim bindings to RubyMine, and not be a full Vim emulator.
From [RubyMine's blog](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/ruby/2009/08/rubymine-for-vim-addicts/), the supported features are:

- Motion keys
- Deletion/Changing
- Insert mode commands
- Marks
- Registers
- VIM undo/redo
- Visual mode commands
- Some Ex commands
- Some :set options
- Full VIM regular expressions for search and search/replace
- Macros
- Diagraphs
- Command line history
- Search history
- Jumplists
- VIM help

If none of their themes work, maybe talk to their support people or request the feature? But it seems they'd be unlikely to add it when they have a variety of their own color schemes.

Comment: I have already the files in my home directory atm and it all works in Vim. But I want it to work in RubyMine as well.