# Intellij IdeaVim change keys

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, ideavim

I would really like to be able to use IdeaVIM but I am unable to figure out where I can set my custom vim key mappings. For example instead of using <kbd>Esc</kbd> I would like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and instead of using <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> I like to use <kbd>w</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>.

I have all these already set in my `.vimrc` but IdeaVIM failed to load them. I can copy them over manually to whatever file is needed but there is no documentation on how to do this.

Comment: The [IdeaVim FAQ](http://ideavim.sourceforge.net/faq.php) seems to address this.

Comment: Hi I looked at that link before I posted and also looked at the Vim.xml and couldn't figure out how to change the key mappings. I need to change the movement keys so I searched that Vim.xml file for j and couldn't find anything. Could you give me an example of a simple key mapping? thanks

Comment: Please vote for the feature request [VIM-288](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-288): Support key mapping commands from `.vimrc`.

Comment: I'm new to IdeaVim, but it could be that the IDE is handling the keystrokes, not IdeaVim? If you want to change how that's done, you can manage "Vim Emulation" settings in `File | Settings | Editor | Vim Emulation` on PC, or `Settings | Editor | Vim Emulation` on Mac

Comment: Yooo IdeaVim is soo much better than VSCode's Vim offerings.  So many more features just frickin work!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I've done this myself, and its pretty easy in IntelliJ 11. I know that in previous versions (9, maybe?) setting up keymap values is significantly different.

In IntelliJ 11 you can do the following:

1. Go to `Settings`
2. Select `Keymap` from the left menu
3. Search for `Exit Insert Mode` on the right side and associate whatever key you want to use, such as <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd>

Comment: Nice! The one weird thing I see is that all of the keys are on one line. It says keys and then one long string... does your's look like that?

Comment: @gdoubleod: Mine looks like that, too. I really wish I could use 'jk' as my esc in ideavim. If I try to make it a two-stroke gesture, it just breaks j in normal mode.

Comment: @danneu: There is currently an [issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-518) on the JetBrains' bug tracker addressing precisely this problem. Vote up!

Comment: I use `jj` to exit insert mode.  Creating a keymap using this method prevents the practical use of `j` in normal mode (such as trying to go down by three lines `jjj`).  To avoid this, create `.ideavimrc` and put `:imap jj <Esc>` into it.

Comment: Another popuplar option is `:imap jk <Esc>`

Answer (score 35):

As of IdeaVim 0.35 (released 2014-05-15), key mappings in `~/.ideavimrc` are supported.  You can put `source ~/.vimrc` in that file if you want to include mappings from `~/.vimrc`.

[Release announcement](https://twitter.com/ideavim/status/460815026413404160)

[VIM-288](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-288)

(Note: This question could probably be considered a duplicate of this [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5585687/2562319) StackOverflow question.)

Comment: if you don't have the file ~/.ideavimrc then you can just simply create it. Just write `source ~/.vimrc` or source wherever your .vimrc file is. Restart pycharm.

Comment: On Windows, .ideavimrc should live in C:\Users\%USERNAME%\

Answer (score 6):

If you like to have Vim plugin installed (I find it very handy for typing) and at the same time have <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> working for copy and paste actions, do the following:

In the IntelliJ Idea, click on `File` > `Setting`.  On the left pane, expand `Editor` and click on `Vim Emulation`.

Here, under the `Shortcut` column, find <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and change it's Handler (under `Handler` column) to `IDE` instead of `Vim`.

Repeat it for <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> as well and hit `Apply` and `Ok`.

Now, you should be able to use the keyboard shortcuts for copy and paste while keeping the Vim Emulator enabled.

Comment: I couldnt find that option anywhere, lol.... thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ 12.1:

1. Go to `Settings`
2. Select `Keymap` from the left menu
3. Find *`Escape`* under the `Editor Actions` section and add the <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> shortcut there.  ("Escape" under the "IdeaVim" section didn't work for me)

Following the same steps, but replacing "Escape" with "Exit Insert Mode" only partially worked for me.  It exited insert mode correctly but ignored the following keystroke. So typing <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>,<kbd>j</kbd>,<kbd>j</kbd> would exit insert but only go up one line instead of two.