# Moving carret quickly in PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

In VIM, we can move forward 3 words with <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> and move backward 3 words with <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>.

Any chance we can do this in PHPStorm?

If no, any idea how to move the carret quickly within a line without going forward word by word with <kbd>⌥</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [IdeaVim plug-in](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&pluginId=164) for PhpStorm, did you try it?

Comment: This is just awesome! This plugin is very well rated, and works amazingly well! Thanks @CrazyCoder.

Comment: The only downside is that remapping doesn't seem to work... for example `:inoremap jk <esc>` to assimilate the `ESC` to `jk`

Comment: You are welcome to report plug-in issues [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/VIM).

Comment: All good @CrazyCoder, this person had a similar [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149187/intellij-ideavim-change-keys).