# How to rebind Comand Mode key in WebStorm's VimIdea plugin?

Tags: vim, sublimetext3, webstorm

I usually used Sublime 3 with Vimtage Mode, but now I need to use the WebStorm IDE. I can not write code without Vim-codes, I install the plug-in VimIdea for it. But vim command mode defaults to the ESC key. This is not convenient for me.

In Sublime 3, I easily changed it to a double click 'i' in the ST3 config, but I'm new to WebStorm, and I do not know how to change the plugin's settings. In ST3, Vim goes in general by default without any plugins.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10195639/783119 perhaps? In any case: `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` -- look for VimIdea supplied actions (should be listed under proper subnode in `Plugins` node)

Answer (score 1):

Like regular vim, ideaVim can use an 'rc' file for configuration.

To switch back to command mode from insert mode by pressing 'i' twice, add this line to your ~/.ideavimrc file. (On Windows: %USERPROFILE%/_ideavimrc):

```
inoremap ii <esc>
```