# Ideavim, use custom keys

Tags: pycharm, ideavim

I am using PyCharm + Ideavim and I am pretty happy with it.

However, is there any way I can change from INSERT to NORMAL mode using 'jk' instead of ESC or Ctrl-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it's not possible to remap keys in IdeaVim. You can only customize standard PyCharm shortcuts using Settings|Keymap. Please vote for the feature request [VIM-288](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-288).

Comment: This answer is no longer true, see below

Answer (score 10):

IdeaVim version 0.35 (released 2014-05-15) reads settings and key bindings from `~/.ideavimrc`.  You can put `source ~/.vimrc` in that file if you want to include mappings from `~/.vimrc`.

0.33 and 0.34 read `~/.vimrc` directly.

0.33 (released 2014-04-28) was the first version to implement [VIM-288](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-288), including things like mapping <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> to <kbd>ESC</kbd>.  It works great, and there's a new *Vim Emulation* section in the IDEA preferences that lists all the conflicts between `~/.vimrc` mappings and Intellij mappings, and lets you resolve the conflicts by assigning the keys to either IDEA or IdeaVim.  Here is the [release announcement](https://twitter.com/ideavim/status/460815026413404160) on twitter.

(Note: This question could probably be considered a duplicate of this [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5585687/2562319) StackOverflow question, and my answer here is taken from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23371030/2562319) there.)

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer nowadays.