# Shortcut key to indent a block of text with IdeaVim and Phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm, indentation, ideavim

Without IdeaVim in PhpStorm, the tab key can be used to indent a selected block of text. However, I'm interested to know if there's a shortcut key that does the same thing with the IdeaVim plugin installed (without losing any functionality that the tab key otherwise has).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

See [Indent multiple lines quickly in vi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235839/how-do-i-indent-multiple-lines-quickly-in-vi)

You must be in normal mode, i.e. go `Esc` before indenting.

You can select a block of lines with `Shift+V`, then up/down arrows, then `>` to indent (`<` reverses indent).

Comment: Great, that looks pretty good. I notice though that once I've done one indent on a selected block, it becomes deselected. If you know a way to keep it selected, please let me know! Thanks again.

Comment: You can specify the number of indents before the `<` or `>` command. Like, `2>` indents 2 times. You're welcome.

Comment: There is the `.` command in vim, which repeats last command, that would be a lot better than calculating (even with the vertical lines in phpstorm which helps you to do that). It seems IdeaVim is broken in this matter: a dot command after a block indent only indents one line...

Comment: Yes, I agree with this feature requets. I program in python and when I refactor I tend to move function bodies around and changing indentation quite a bit. Right now I can change indentation 1 level by doing a block visualization and indenting that part. But when I enter the . command (like it works in normal vim) it only applies to the last row and not the whole selection. 

I haven't found a way to easily change indentation levels on multiple rows more than one step on the current version (0.37).

Thanks for a great plugin btw :)

Comment: The license is GPL, the IdeaVim source is in Github, it's just a matter of dedication, knowledge and a pull request.

Comment: As I stumbled upon this in 2019, I want to note that the `.` command now works properly in IntelliJ IDEs

Answer (score 21):

I think following settings are what you want! :)

Put the followings to ~/.ideavimrc

```
nnoremap <Tab> >>_
nnoremap <S-Tab> <<_
inoremap <S-Tab> <C-D>
vnoremap <Tab> >gv
vnoremap <S-Tab> <gv
```

ideavim support vimrc with .ideavimrc

also see: [Is there a way to get IdeaVIM to honor the mappings from my .vimrc file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585687/is-there-a-way-to-get-ideavim-to-honor-the-mappings-from-my-vimrc-file)

Comment: Works for me. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!