# How can I disable visual mode in IdeaVIM?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, ideavim

I'm using PyCharm with the IDEAVim plugin. Whenever I highlight text in insert mode and hit backspace, my highlighted text just moves to the left more instead of deleting it.

What can I add to my .ideavimrc to disable visual mode and just delete text if I ever highlight text and hit backspace?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can remap backspace to `d` in visual mode.

Put `vnoremap <BS> d` in your `.ideavimrc`

Comment: This works great! Thanks. For newbies, here's where to create that file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138992/vimrc-for-intellij-ideas-vim-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not possible. Feel free to file a bug to [IdeaVim's issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM).