# How to change the behavior of Backspace key in Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

I started using IntelliJ Idea 14.1.4 a couple days ago.

I am getting crazy over the backspace functionality. Instead of deleting the characters, it selects it. I am raging at this. I have searched trough the settings and couldn't find a way to turn it off.

Any help? I can't find the "toggle" button on the settings?

Comment: Another problem is, when I select a text, the only way to remove it is by using the delete button/key. Backspace, then, deselect what I have selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Disabling/Uninstalling the ideaVim plugin seamed to fix the problem for me. The plugin description hints that you can configure it via a configuration script in ~/.ideavimrc, which there may also be options to get "normal" behaviour with the plugin installed but I haven't looked into that though, because the plugin doesn't seems all that useful to me. I hope this helps other people to fix there issues with Intellij 14.

This is from [Intellij 14 weird editor/cursor behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788552/intellij-14-weird-editor-cursor-behaviour)

Comment: I was just adding the edit for this same answer that I too have found. Thanks.

Comment: For those wanting to _keep_ IdeaVIM while getting back Backspace functionality, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42517158/925913).